# Syntax error when trying to add columns to table in DBeaver (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, errors, alter-table, syntax

I've tried this a few different ways but every time I get a syntax error when trying to add columns to a table.

I'm new to databases so it's probably something basic that I'm doing wrong, but I just don't see why this isn't working.

Any input would be appreciated.

P.S. at the end of the query line there is a ";"... You just can't see it in the screenshot.

So far I've tried changing "add columns" to "add column" and just "add" followed by the columns. I'm aware I can just use the GUI to copy columns in DBeaver but I'd rather get this SQL working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) the correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table>
    ADD COLUMN <column name> <column type>,
    ADD COLUMN <column name> <column type>,
    ADD COLUMN <column name> <column type>;
```

Have a look at Postgres tutorials on [PostgreSQL ADD COLUMN: Add One Or More Columns To a Table](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-add-column/).

I've set up a minimal example that reproduces your error:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (id int);

ALTER TABLE newtable
    ADD COLUMNS f1 float8, f2 int;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "float8"
>   LINE 2:     ADD COLUMNS f1 float8, f2 int;                          ^

```
ALTER TABLE newtable
    ADD COLUMN f1 float8, f2 int, f3 text;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "f2"
>   LINE 2:     ADD COLUMN f1 float8, f2 int, f3 text;

Using the correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE newtable
    ADD COLUMN f1 float8,
    ADD COLUMN f2 int,
    ADD COLUMN f3 text;
✓
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f5ecc382856627a1d4884417369e9e5d)*

Comment: Thanks McNets, using the correct syntax at the bottom of your post worked. From what I read on other posts I was under the impression that you could add multiple columns without multiple "add column" statements using a syntax like: ALTER TABLE newtable ADD COLUMN (column1 float8, column2 int, etc.);... but I don't see that anywhere in the official docs. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad to help.